# Query on RMI working

Tags: ejb, rmi

I don't get one thing in RMI. It's a bit confusing actually.

On client side, we have the business interface (Hello.class), the client code (HelloClient.class) and the remote stub (probably Hello_stub.class) and on server side we have the server code (HelloImpl.class), the business interface (Hello.class) and the skeleton .

For Java 5 onwards, we don't create stubs but still they are c=in picture i believe.

So, how does the communication happen ?

The client calls method on Hello.class which then calls Hello_stub.class for all n/w operations. The Hello_stub.class calls the skeleton which then calls Hello.class and then calls methods on HelloImpl.class ?

I am a bit confused after reading Head first EJB :) .It would be glad if someone clarified it.

Comment: try checking this page out http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/rmi/relnotes.html

Answer (score 2):

When the stub's method is called:

1. It gets a TCP connection to s target out of the client connection pool, or creates one if there isn't a pooled connection
2. Bundles up the call and the arguments into a serializable object.
3. Writes the object to the connection along with some other stuff like a JRMP protocol header and a remote objectID.
4. Reads the reply object from the connection.
5. Returns the connection to the pool, where it gets closed after a certain idle time.
6. If the reply object is an exception, throws it.
7. Otherwise returns the reply object as the method result.

At the server, a thread sits on the listening socket, accepting connections, creating threads, and dispatching incoming remote calls to the correct remote object via the specified object ID.

This is done via reflection. RMI skeletons haven't been used since 1998, except in the case of stubs you deliberately generate with `rmic -v1.1`, but the principle is the same either way.